# If checkbox selected append his textValue into another span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown checkbox for which I want to `get` checkbox value and `append` a `<span>` when checkbox is checked after `<input type="text" class="form-control">`. When checkbox is unchecked I want to remove appended span.

this is what I've tried:

```
$ ('.chkb:checkbox').click(function(){
  if ($(".chkb").prop('checked') == true){
     var textName = $('.chkb:checked').next( '.txt' ).text();

     $( ".input-append" ).append('<span class="input-group-addon vss"> ' + textName +'</span>');
    //alert(textName);
}
   else{
    $( ".vss" ).remove();
}
})
```

It is not working so great my script because if I select more checkbox options the append is for every checked element once again and remove only when I uncheck last checkbox.

[**Here is a small fiddle example:**](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5729/)

Comment: Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5735/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//keep dropdown open
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('drop-down-stay')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

//find checkbox span name and insert into appended span
$ ('.chkb:checkbox').click(function(){
  if ($(this).prop('checked')){
     var textName = $(this).next( '.txt' ).text();

     $( ".input-append" ).append('<span class="input-group-addon vss"> ' + textName +'</span>');
    //alert(textName);
}
   else{
    //build again the checked ones   
    $( ".vss" ).remove();
       $ ('.chkb:checkbox:checked').each(function(){                   

     $( ".input-append" ).append('<span class="input-group-addon vss"> ' +  $(this).next( '.txt' ).text()+'</span>');
       });
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `$(".chkb")` with `$(this)` inside click event callback function. Currently you check all of the checkboxes values in the click event callback function. `$(this)` refers to the clicked checkbox. So `$(this).prop('checked')` will refer to the last clicked checkboxes value. You can go from there to solve the problem that you have :)

Answer (score 1):

Just append in your code the next line in click:

```
$( ".vss" ).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5737/

```
//find checkbox span name and insert into appended span
$ ('.chkb:checkbox').click(function(){
    $( ".vss" ).remove();
  if ($(".chkb").prop('checked') == true){
     var textName = $('.chkb:checked').next( '.txt' ).text();

     $( ".input-append" ).append('<span class="input-group-addon vss"> ' + textName +'</span>');
    //alert(textName);
}
   else{
    $( ".vss" ).remove();
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.chkb:checkbox').click(function () {
    var items = $('.chkb:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return '<span class="input-group-addon vss"> ' + $(this).next('.txt').text() + '</span>'
    }).get();
    $(".input-append .vss").remove()
    $(".input-append").append(items.join(''));
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fL4BF/)